# Make one extra variable, program doesn't work

Tags: java, string

My task is to create a program which asks the user to enter a year, a first name and a last name. It then takes the last 2 numbers of the year, the whole last name, and the first letter of the first name and formats them into an email like this: 16SmithJ@mymail.co.uk. It places this email in a text file, which doesn't need to be printed. At the end, it asks if the user wishes to repeat the process again to make a new email.

This is my program, and it isn't fully complete yet. I have it working, but when I go to implement the part which repeats it if wanted, the email is no longer made in the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("7D_mail.txt"));
    boolean done = false;
    while (done==false){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter the year (e.g 2016) > ");
    String year = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Enter your first name > ");
    String fname = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Enter your last name > ");
    String lname = kb.nextLine();
    pw.write (year.substring(2)+lname+fname.charAt(0)+"@mymail.co.uk");
    System.out.print ("*** Email created - another one? (Y/N)");

    pw.close();
    }


}
```

This program above works, but if I then add one line after the last one (**String answer = kb.nextLine();**), to make a new string for the answer, it no longer works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("7D_mail.txt"));
    boolean done = false;
    while (done==false){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter the year (e.g 2016) > ");
    String year = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Enter your first name > ");
    String fname = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print ("Enter your last name > ");
    String lname = kb.nextLine();
    pw.write (year.substring(2)+lname+fname.charAt(0)+"@mymail.co.uk");
    System.out.print ("*** Email created - another one? (Y/N)");
    String answer = kb.nextLine();

    pw.close();
    }


}
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: It seems like you `close` the file after the very first run of the loop.

Comment: Change `done = true;` to `done = answer.equals("N");`. Also, you can use `!done` instead of `done == false`. Make sure you don't close the `PrintWriter` if `done` is `false`.

Comment: Still doesn't work I'm afraid @Titus

Comment: And @tobias_k, even without done = true, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try new FileWriter("7D_mail.txt",true) in order to append to the file.The boolean parameter here tells  if you want to append to the file or not.

Comment: Anyone got anthing else? I still haven't got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it stopped working. You are unconditionally setting "done" to true after you take the user's repsonse, so it exits. Wrap "done = true" in a condition that checks for the value of "answer" to be "Y".

Comment: Makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value 'done' is set to true after the first iteration of the loop and the loop never gets a chance to run again.

Besides, you close the PrintWriter after one iteration as well.

What I would suggest is this change:

```
if(answer.equals("N")){
    done = true;
    pw.close();
}
```

Comment: This answer was in response to the initial code in his question. He seems to have changed the code in the question a little by removing the line that sets the value of done = true.

Comment: I've removed that part because it being there made no difference and many people are suggesting changing it, which isn't the problem.

Comment: Did you try my solution? You shouldn't close the PrintWriter right away. That's why even though the loop enters the second iteration, it doesn't write to the file, because you've closed the PrintWriter in the first iteration.

Answer (score -1):

Try using System.out.println (); after printing the question to avoid exceptions (you can read the api here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).